# KCfinder, how to pass or send the url variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im sorry if the title is seem confusing :(

I Using KC Finder to develop my CMS file manager

i have HTML code like this

```
<input type="text" name="url-1" value="" />
<button class="button-primary" onclick="openKCFinder_singleFile(); return false;">Insert</button>
```

here is the content of `openKCFinder_singleFile()`

```
function openKCFinder_singleFile() {
window.KCFinder = {};
window.KCFinder.callBack = function(url) {
    window.KCFinder = null;
    console.log(url) // URL is the call back result from KCfinder, example: /image/a.jpg
};
window.open('/wp-content/plugins/kcfinder/browse.php', 'kcfinder_single');
}
```

My Question is, how to set the value `input` with the value i get from `kcfinder`, as you can see we get the value from variable `url`, how to pass that to set as input value?

if the code in jQuery script, i really appreciate it :)

Many Thanks

GusDe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can simply add :

```
$('#url-1').val(url);
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/NTWqg/).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer of user284291, but there is a but :) if you are using this function in a page which does not load jquery, you can send the url by replacing
`$('#url-1').val(url);`
with
`var x = document.getelementbyid('url-1'); x.setAttribute('value', url);`